# Passing json data from mongodb query to javascript variable client side using express and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mapbox-gl-js

I am running into trouble sending some json data from a mongodb query server side to a javascript variable client-side with express. I am using Mapbox Gl-Js and I need to use some json data from a mongodb server to load a geojson line on the page. 
Here is my route:

```
# /routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var collection = db.get().collection('route');
    collection.find({ id : "route" }).toArray(function(err, docs){
        res.render('index', {
            "data" : docs
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I know this query works server side. Now, I need to pass this geojson data to a javascript file on the client side. It is maybe worth mentioning that this file is not rendered by the router, but rather the index.jade file is rendered and this file is referenced in there.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'REDACTED';
# /public/map.js
// check if mapbox is supported on client's browser
if (!mapboxgl.supported()) {
  alert('Your browser is not supported. Please use a more modern browser.');
} else {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'REDACTED', //stylesheet location
        center: [48.010062, 29.310335 ], // starting position
        zoom: 11 // starting zoom
    });
}
// make arabic text work
mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin('https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-
js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.1.0/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js');
// add navigation and geolocation controls
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl());

var json_data = JSON.stringify(data)
console.log(json_data);
```

The console.log time throws a ReferenceError. How can I fix this? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the router isn't rendering this page directly?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to access the `jade` template data in javascript is not correct. You can declare the variable in jade file, then can use it in `js` file. e.g.

**index.jade**

```
script(type='text/javascript').                                                
   var json_data = JSON.stringify(data)
script(src='/public/map.js')
```

**/public/map.js**

```
console.log(json_data);
```